CSS isolation in mvc does not generate hash attributes
I created a component _Card.cshtml and its corresponding style file _Card.cshtml.css that looks like this:
.test {
   color: red;
   background-color: red;
}
.test_1 {
   color: blue;
   background-color: blue;
}

In the _Card.cshtml component, I applied the styles as follows:
<div class="test">
   some text
   <div class="test_1">
       some more text
   </div>
</div>

I also added the CSS link to the Layout file:
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="ProjectName.styles.css" />
</head>

In the Sources tab of the browser, I see that the generated ProjectName.styles.css file contains the following:
/* _content/ProjectName/Views/_Card.cshtml.rz.scp.css */
.test[b-vf93ptq5bl] {
   color: red;
   background-color: red;
}
.test_1[b-vf93ptq5bl] {
   color: blue;
   background-color: blue;
}

However, the generated HTML does not include the attributes like b-vf93ptq5bl, causing the styles not to be applied. Html from browser:
<div class="test">
   some text
   <div class="test_1">
       some more text
   </div>
</div>

Why weren't the hash-attributes autogenerated and added to the HTML? How can I fix this?

May I know if you are working on .net core MVC application or .net core razor web app? In the title I can see MVC, I just want to double confirm it with you.

I had a test both in razor web app and mvc app, and according to /* _content/ProjectName/Views/_Card.cshtml.rz.scp.css */, I'm afraid you are working on an MVC application. Then in my side, I can't reproduce your issue. I put _Card.cshtml and _Card.cshtml.css into Shared folder. What I'm concerned is that when I use <link rel="stylesheet" href="ProjectName.styles.css" /> in my side, I will get 40004 error, by default it's <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/ProjectName.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" /> in my _Layout.cshtml

Could you please share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue? Such as where the cshtml is placed and how you render it. Maybe render as partial view? Till now, when I try to return PartialView("Views/Shared/_Card.cshtml"); then only the html content will be returned when I call the controller action, in other test, css isolation worked well.
